# AngularJS - HTTP post request: OPTIONS failed net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: angularjs, http, post

I have an AngularJS web app that posts requests to the server.
It used to work fine.

But since today it fails most of the time (not systematically) in the OPTIONS request with the error:  net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE.

Could someone help me and explain to me what happens ?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Use following to post the request

```
 $http.post('url',{data:'your data'}).
  success(function(data,status,headers){
        // do your stuff
 })
 .error(function(data,status,headers){
    // error handling
  });
```

and you should check on server side like in php ,the request method

```
 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='OPTIONS')
      exit(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying uploading a file from 2 MB and I got the response:

```
net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

I reviewed the log from my balance server (NGINX) and it showed:

```
[error] 5#5: *15 client intended to send too large body: 2545329 bytes
```

In order to solve it, you have to add the following parameter in NGINX

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
    client_max_body_size 4m;
}
```